# android strange float maths

Tags: android, math, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

i get very odd behaviour from simple float maths. eg.

```
//create a float with value of 1.0
float f = 1.0;
//take 0.1 from its value
f -=0.1;
```

for the first few times when i minus 0.1 it returns 0.9, 0.8, 0.7......
then for some reason it will return 0.699999999999, 0.59999999999 and so on.
to say this is unexpected is an understatement.

so to fix this i either need to know why it would do this
or a math function similar to Round(float) where it will round the number from 0.5999999 to 0.6.

thank you

edit, 
ok sorry for asking lol
any fix available? like Round(float) kinda thing?

other edit:
for the next person to ask about this heres a fix

```
final DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
myFormat.format(myFloatValue)
```

this will change myFloatValue 0.599999 into 0.6

Comment: This is probably the single most-often asked question on all of StackOverflow, across all programming languages.

Comment: A short answer: http://floating-point-gui.de/. The long answer: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.

Comment: ..and yet again..  This is entirely expected behaviour.  We get about one a day of these. Not all decimal numbers can be exactly represented in floating-point binary - 'Computer Science 101'.

Comment: so a Round(float) equivalent exists or not? any way to show 0.6 instead of 0.5999999?

Comment: And this is the reason why its often a bad idea to compare floats like *if ( f == 23.52f ) {...}*.

Comment: Generally if you run into this problem and need correct handling then you should store all your fractional values in integers (multiplied with 10^4 for example), or use java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer is a finite device, so it stores floating point numbers with a finite precision.  And it stores them as binary floating point numbers -- that is relative to base 2 instead of base 10.  A number with a finite representation as a decimal fraction doesn't necessarily have a finite representation as a binary number, so it must be rounded to be stored in a finite computer.  In this example, `0.1` will be rounded to

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

when stored as a double precision floating point number, so you actually subtract a bit more than `0.1` in each step.

Comment: ok sorry for being the guy that asks this today :s so any chance of a fix?

Comment: @user1033558: There is nothing broken, so you can't fix it.  What's your actual problem?

Comment: the problem is that i display this number, 0.599999999999 looks rubbish. 0.6 would be preferable.

Comment: Try something like this to format your floating point number
`format("%.1f", 123.456f)` to a single decimal place.  You can read more about formats [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a fundamental limitation of the floating point representation. Certain numbers, such as 0.1, are not exactly representable using base-2 arithmetic with finite precision.